# using web services to access a database

Tags: .net, sql, rest, soap, ado

For my final year of computer science at uni I have to create a .net application w/ database access using agile development.

I have an mdf file hosted on a university web-server and I need many client applications to connect to this database file.

Is there a way I can implement concurrent access to this database without having to install sql express on the web server?

Would creating a web-service (maybe using Rest/Soap) allow me to open multiple connections to the mdf file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer to the questions in paragraph 3 and 4 of your question is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: If you are using a **RDBMS** then you should have a database server(Like **SqlServer**, **MySQL**) installed in **webserver** ... So, when you booking web server, make sure that it has your required database server ..

**Second** : **Yes** ..But concurrent database access and web-services(Rest/Soap) calls are different aspect.. If your database server allow (Most of them allow including SQLServer) concurrency then it's possible ...